# Outline Number Column to Parent and Child

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

have db table with Outline Number as:

```
PID    Task    OutlineNumber
------------------------------
1      Task1       0
2      Task2       1
3      Task3       1.1
4      Task4       1.1.1
5      Task5       2
6      Task6       2.1
7      Task7       2.1.1
```

I want to select this data as:

```
PID    Task     CatID SubCatID
------------------------------
1      Task1     0      NULL
2      Task2     1       1
3      Task3     1       2
4      Task4     1       3
5      Task5     2      NULL 
6      Task6     2       5
7      Task7     2       6
```

I'm using SQLExpress 2005

Comment: How far nested can the outlinenumber go?  Is the 2.1.1 the longest string you'll have there, or will you have a 2.1.1.1.1.1?

Comment: this method of nesting isn't efficient. try to have a look at this: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data (the last half, closure tables)

Comment: So, why does `Task2` has `SubCatID` equal to 1 but `Task5` doesn't have `SubCatID` equal to 2?

Comment: where does the SubCatID come from? As the values don't appear in your source data? Is it some form of incremental number (counting over the nulls)?!

Comment: @Tanner, As I see it, it should be the `PID` from the "Parent" task. The problem with my theory is that `PID = 2` has `PID = 1` as the parent, but `PID = 5` doesn't have `PID = 2` as a parent. Doesn't seem consistent

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the depth of OutlineNumber yet, I'll offer a solution based upon my usual ordering of 4-part version numbers using parsename:

```
;with VNums as (
    select PID
        , Task
        , OutlineNumber
        , OutlineNumber + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(OutlineNumber) - len(replace(OutlineNumber, '.', '')))) as VNum
    from MyTable
), VOrders as (
    select PID
        , Task
        , OutlineNumber
        , VNum
        , row_number() over (order by cast(parsename(VNum, 4) as int), cast(parsename(VNum, 3) as int), cast(parsename(VNum, 2) as int), cast(parsename(VNum, 1) as int)) as VOrder
    from VNums
)
select PID
    , Task
    , parsename(VNum, 4) as CatID
    , case when OutlineNumber not like '%.%' then null else VOrder - 1 end as SubCatID
from VOrders
order by VOrder;
```

This yields:

```
PID    Task     CatID SubCatID
------------------------------
1      Task1     0    NULL
2      Task2     1    NULL -- 1 in OP's example
3      Task3     1    2
4      Task4     1    3
5      Task5     2    NULL 
6      Task6     2    5
7      Task7     2    6
```

I'm simply setting the SubCatID to an overall zero-based index of version numbers, but null in the case where there's no "." or "minor version".

I'll second @Lamak's comment and admit that I can't see how the SubCatID for Task2 and Task5 aren't both null (outside of *guessing* at things such as "there's no SubCatID for 0 so make the next CatID non-null").

To go to infinite depth of OutlineNumber, including nodes that can be greater than 9, the solution would possibly take the form of a recursive CTE, or maybe a proc with dynamic SQL in it.